# Haskell Read type Inference

Tags: haskell, type-inference, typeclass

I have written my own implementation of a graph based on adjacency matrices and made instance of the `Read` class.

My graph takes a type as input which will be the type of the edges.

If I try expression like

```
read " - - 8 \n - 9 - \n 1 2 3" :: GraphADJ Int
```

it works just fine (it's a graph with 3 nodes, and the edge from first node to the third, from the second to the second and from the third to all the nodes).

What I wanted to do is to be able to not tell the type inference the type of the edges, but to put them into a context (like in `read"4"+3`).

I have the function `insertEdge` which takes a graph, a couple of nodes and the new edge.

```
insertEdge :: Graph g n e => g -> (n, n) -> e -> g
```

(`Graph` is the general class for the graph which `GraphADJ` is made instance of)

So when I try to do

```
 insertEdge (read " - - 8 \n - 9 - \n 1 2 3" :: GraphADJ Int) (1,2) 3
```

it works just fine, but if I don't make the type explicit, I get the error
`Ambiguous type variables` .

Did I forget something in the `Read` or a I missing something?

Comment: Just curious, but why aren't you simply `deriving (Read)` and using a separate function(s) for a custom serialized format?

Comment: I'm not so sure what you mean by "custom serialized format", anyway I made my graph instance of read because was part of my assignment (which is concluded now).

Comment: Does your `GraphADJ` type also make sense with an `Integer` parameter, i.e. would `read " - - 8 \n - 9 - \n 1 2 3" :: GraphADJ Integer` also work? I'm guessing it does, and you're running into problems because numeric literals in Haskell are polymorphic. Give it a try with `Char`acters instead of numbers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is compiler does not have enough info to infer type for read.

Even if you provide type info for `n` to `Int` and `e` to `Int` compiler still does not have information of `g`. All it knows that `g` is a type with an instance for `Graph g  Int Int`. It still can not infer `g` even if there is single type which inhabit such an instance.

Compiler can not automatically see that in the current scope there is only on such type which has such a instance as allowing such behavior might result in breaking of code by importing modules.

So the solution would be either to provide explicit signature or to make a specialized version of `insertEdge` providing explicit concrete types to provide enough information for `read`. The latter would be useful if you are using it for the same type at more than one place.

Comment: I tought about that and I have tried also 

`insertEdge (read " - - 8 \n - 9 - \n 1 2 3" ) (1,2) (3 :: Int)`

but I still got an error (I should have posted in the main post, sorry)

Comment: `insertEdge (read " - - 8 \n - 9 - \n 1 2 3" ) (1 :: Int,2 ) (3 :: Int)`

and

`insertEdge (read " - - 8 \n - 9 - \n 1 2 3" ) ((1,2) :: (Int,Int)) (3 :: Int)`

still result me in 

`No instance for (Graph g0 Int Int)`

I feel like there's some theoretical background I miss.

Comment: @user1544128 Simply put, even if you give an explicit type to the Ints, the compiler cannot possibly guess that you want to use the specific implementation `GraphADJ`, since the call to `insertEdge` works with any instance of `Graph`. Therefore the `g` in `Graph g Int Int` remains ambiguous.